# ChatSharp IRC Throwing Execption When Joining a Channel That Exists

Tags: c#, irc

https://github.com/SirCmpwn/ChatSharp
[image: Amazing Source]

So, I am working on a bot that will connect to the Osu (Get mad Peppy) [IRC](https://osu.ppy.sh/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat)

But now when I am joining the channel it keeps throwing the key doesn't exist in the dictonary, I can't tell if it's a problem with the library or something else. However I know the channel exists (because it's in the documentation AND I can join it fine in HexChat.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Error: [image]

Comment: Can you paste the exception? This will be related to the library you are using, `IRC` creates a channel on `JOIN` if it does not exist on the server.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c553ei

Comment: can you put this as part of your question please? It will allow others to view the exception quicker.

Comment: Also, please edit the question to provide all **relevant** code, in a code block (**not** an image).

Comment: What more can I add? I gave you the block it's failing on. All I have is an event setup that fires correctly, however when I say Client.JoinChannel it fails citing the channel doesn't exist. I don't know what else to provide.

Comment: Attempting a bump here, I haven't found anything more about this.